# Mysql sum of rows as row value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've stucked with some mysql problem with sum. I need a table of invoices like this:

```
id invoice_num  net_value  date             total_month
_______________________________________________________
1  100          100.00     21.01.2013       500.00
2  101          300.00     22.01.2013       500.00
3  102          100.00     23.01.2013       500.00
4  103          900.00     01.02.2013       900.00
.
.
.
```

The problem is how to calculate sum of all invoices for a month (i.e. january as above) and display this sum as a value in last column for invoices from january.
Generaly spoken, I need sum of values of invoices grouped by month but displayed in each row.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the data type on date column? You can use `GROUP BY MONTH(date)`?

Comment: if your date column looks liek that, update it to ISO with str_to_date so SQL can see it as a date. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not have an iso date, make it happen

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01.5.2013','%d.%m.%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

your query when date is in ISO:

```
SELECT invoices.id, invoices.invoice_num, invoices.net_value, invoices.date, monthly.total_month
FROM invoices
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT month(date) AS MONTH,
          sum(net_value) AS total_month
   FROM invoices group by month(date)) AS monthly ON monthly.MONTH=MONTH(invoices.date)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however in case when there's lot of data inner select will be very inefficient. About about date formatit's not an issue, the problem is that grouping gives less column summed by value and I need the same number of column with the sum in one field...

Comment: 1. this is the optimised way to do it. In case of a lot of data, you are 'inner selecting' 12 rows per year anyway. Do you have millions of years? No. 
2. Grouping does not reduce the number of columns.
3. Query above returns exactly what you asked for, in the optimal speed way, with one row per day and the monthly sum beside it. Please read which query the grouping is in.
4. Date in string format IS an issue, since the engine cannot do date functions on strings.

Comment: Not issue I meand not the problem at the moment :) however very thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,invoice_num,net_value,month(date),sum(total_month) as total_month 
from invoices
group by month(date)
```

Comment: illegal use of grouping. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html
you have non aggregated fields outside of your grouping - these will return the first line value, and not correct values